# What is wrong with my implementation of RMSE?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The code below is an implementation of RMSE in matlab. when I try to run it in the Command Window, I get the following error:

> Undefined function or method 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
I = imread ('images.jpg');
figure(1), imshow (I,[]);
R= imread ('Gray Image.jpg');
figure(2), imshow (R,[]);
impixelinfo
modi_size = (R);
[r,c]= size(I);
for i = 1 : r ;
    for j = 1: c ;
        rmse1 = sqrt(1/r * c);
        rmse2 = (I(i,j)- R(i,j))^2 ;
        RMSE = rmse1 * sqrt((symsum (rmse2,0,r))* (symsum(rmse2,0,c))) ;
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, those semicolons at the end of your two `for` lines are useless. You can safely get rid of them.

Comment: `symsum` is from symbolic math toolbox. Why do you need symbolic math here? If you do not, use `sum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your definition of RMSE is wrong.  For the mean-squared error, the definition is:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)</sup>

If you want the **root** mean-squared error, simply take the square root of this result.  Your `for` loop is not accumulating the sum of squared deviations properly.  In addition, `rmse1` is incorrect.  This is equivalent to saying that `rmse1 = sqrt(c/r)`.  What you really mean is `rmse1 = sqrt(1/(r*c))`.  However, you should scale this **outside** of the sum.  You need to add up all of the sum of squared errors, divide by the total size of the image and **then** take the square root.  Also `symsum` is for **symbolic** mathematics.  You are computing this numerically.  You also need to make your `RMSE` variable an accumulator and you add the error onto this variable.

One last thing I need to mention is that you need to convert your images to `double` or some precision that is beyond `uint8` (which is the data type for your images).  This is because when you are computing the squared errors, you will most likely go beyond the maximum value of 255.  By not doing this, your values are clipped to 255 and that's not what you want.

Therefore, you need to change your code to:

```
%// Removed half of your code.  This is the important part
[r,c]= size(I);

I = double(I);
R = double(R); %// Cast to ensure precision
RMSE = 0;

%// Accumulate sum of squared errors
for i = 1 : r
    for j = 1 : c
        RMSE = RMSE + (I(i,j)- R(i,j))^2;
    end
end

%// Find mean, then square root
RMSE = sqrt(RMSE / (r*c));
```

---

However, the above code is quite inefficient due to the use of `for` loops.  What you can do instead is vectorize the code.  You can do this in one line as (without the casting):

```
I = double(I);
R = double(R);
RMSE = sqrt( mean( (I(:) - R(:)).^2 ) );
```

`I` and `R` get unrolled into single vectors, they each get subtracted element-wise with their squares taken, the average is computed for this result and the square root is taken after.

---

Hope this helps.  Good luck!